# how can i pass different value in Icon button in each Render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want this icon  to render each time with a different state for AudioPathForRecording  but the previous render buttons will keep its value , the problem is that when I render a new Icon the previous Icon value become change and all having the same value , i tried with multiple approaches like constructor , global variable and other but problem remain same

i already tried it with constructor and global variable

```
renderAudio = props => {
   if(this.state.AudioMessage){

   let audioPath = new AudioPath(this.state.AudioPathForRecording)

    this.setState({
      AudioMessage : false
    })
    return(
      <Ionicons
      name="ios-play"
      size={35}
      color={this.state.playAudio ? "red" : "blue"}
      style={{
          left: 90,
          position: "relative",
          shadowColor: "#000",
          shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
          shadowOpacity: 0.5,
          backgroundColor: "transparent"
      }}
      audioPath= {audioPath}
      onPress={() => {
        console.log(audioPath)
      }}
      />
    )
```

Comment: You are sharing the state with all your Ionicons...

Comment: so how can i achive the expected result so that every ioniIcon get different value